# SQL Server Query Alter ID field to make it incremental in a View

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have created a view from two tables morning shift and night shift employees

[image]

My view looks like this:

```
USE Employees
 GO
 CREATE VIEW EmployeesShift
 SELECT MEID AS ID, MEName AS Name, Status, Address
 FROM MorningEmployees
 UNION ALL
 SELECT NEID AS ID, NEName AS Name, Status, Address
 FROM NightEmployees
```

The resulting table looks like this

[image]

However I want the values of ID field to look like this

[image]

Can Anyone help please?

Comment: You should consider having only one Employees table, for all shifts. You can add a shift column to it.

Comment: And how do you want the global row number applied? Morning employees first? Something else? Don't care? What is the purpose of the ID column at all?

Comment: The term "ID" suggests that the value should not change as employees in either shift change over time. If that is correct, then you have a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and will likely need a very different approach / solution.

Comment: Thanks Jarih and Aaron Bertrand for your quick response. I have just posted two samples but my real tables have 600 and 200 rows each table has ID field and creating duplicate ID values. What I want is the ID field values to be incremental e.g 1 - 800.

Comment: Thanks SMor, the ID fields are not changing on each table. I just want to have new ID values for the view.

Comment: And again - why? How will this be used? Jane's "ID" is 1, not 5. Next time you run this query, perhaps someone else will be 5 (maybe Jane changes shift or someone is added to that shift). If you just want a sequential, unique value in your resultset, then use rownumber.

Comment: You are right SMor, is there a way that I can create a new table that combines the two and with new IDs and discard the two tables?

Comment: So now you are asking a very different question and your original post does not match your goal. Surely you have other tables that reference these existing tables - because generally Employees (like Persons) is a fundamental part of most schemas and has many relationships to other tables. You would need to migrate those relationships as well to accomplish your goal. The first thing you should do is make a backup just in case something goes wrong. (cont)

Comment: You can generate DDL from one of your existing tables and use it to create your new table with the desired name. You then just insert into your new table by selecting the rows in the existing two tables. I suggest you use identity columns as your primary key (if not already) and forget about trying to manage the ID "re-alignment".

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

You can use a windowing function to generate a unique ID for every row on the fly

```
select * from (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 10000)) AS id FROM dbo.EmployeesShift) a
order by a.id
```